How can I use plt.ion()?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ion()  # Turn on interactive mode

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

for i in range(10):
    plt.plot(x, y * (i + 1))
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.5)  # Pause to update the plot

plt.ioff()  # Turn off interactive mode
plt.show()  # Display the final plot

I found that the matplotlib function plt.ion() allows me to keep updating the graph. However, when I run the example code or the code I made in my vscode, the graph doesn't update and keeps outputting. How do I fix this?
I'm using virtualenv. I check all library(matplotlib, numpy) are installed in venv.

ion doesn't change the content of the plot. It just changes when the plot window is shown/updated.
In your case, the only thing ion does, is exempting you to call a plt.show(block=False) at first.
Without ion, you would have expected to see 10 curves from this code. Then, with ion, you should expect the exact same result. The purpose of ion is to allow you to watch intermediary stages of a complex plot, when, without ion (or without doing the same manually, with sequences of show(block=False), plt.pause, ...) you would only see the end result (the graph with 10 curves).
So the only thing ion is supposed to help you do, is, rather than having a graph with 10 curves, is having first 1 graph with 1 curve, then a graph with 2 curves, then a graph with 3 curves, ..., then a graph with 10 curves (and therefore watching incrementally your 10 curves graph being built)
If what you wanted was to see a single curve evolving, you need to find a way to animate a curve. Here are 3 ways
reset the graph between each plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ion()  # Turn on interactive mode

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

for i in range(10):
    plt.clf()    # Clear the figure
    plt.ylim(-15,15) # Not strictly necessary. But your example, once working, would be boring without it, since each of your 10 curves are identical to a scale factor...
    plt.plot(x, y * (i + 1))
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.5)  # Pause to update the plot

plt.ioff()  # Turn off interactive mode
plt.show()  # Display the final plot

That is very rudimentary. It is just erasing everything at each iteration.
But that is, I think, what you were expecting.
It would be quite painful to use for a more complex plot, that being said. Because, it forces you to redraw everything, the curve that you want to redraw, but also everything else in the graph (here, that curve is the only thing in the graph, so the pain of the "redraw all" is not visible).
Update plot data
A more correct way would be to update the data of only the plot you want to alter, without touching (and erasing) the rest of the graph.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

data, = plt.plot(x, y)
plt.ylim(-15,15) # Same as before. Not as needed as before, because the `cos` I also draw prevent rescaling, and ensure a visual "anti-boring" reference :D
plt.show(block=False)

plt.plot(x, 5*np.cos(x)) # Just to bear witness that other curves in the graph are kept

for i in range(10):
    data.set_data(x, y * (i + 1))
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.5)  # Pause to update the plot

plt.show()  # Display the final plot. Not needed strictly. But ensure that, if that is the last line of code, the program stay blocked here until the plot window is closed. 

use animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig=plt.figure()
data, = plt.plot(x, y)
plt.ylim(-15,15)
plt.plot(x, 5*np.cos(x)) # Just to bear witness that other curves in the graph are kept

def animate(i):
    data.set_data(x, y * (i + 1))
    return [data] # Return what has been modified

theAnim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=10, interval=500, blit=True, repeat=False) # Note the needed `theAnim` variable. Without it, the garbarge collector would destroy the animation before it is over
plt.show()

It has the advantage to be an "official" way to create animation. It is not particularly easier to write, or more compact. But you can have then some shortcut for some tasks.
Like, saving a animation file. I can produce the following .gif, by just replacing plt.show() by theAnim.save('out.gif')


Very nice answer, +10 and saved for later. I would like to add one option of having fig = plt.figure() and then fig.clf() and fig.canvas.draw(). This does not work on all IDEs but works very nicely in jupyter. In case a subplot is needed, this can be replaced with for ax in axs: ax.cla() to replace to fig.clf() step. I did this approach in this answer
